# Store videos for an iOS app online or offline?

Tags: ios, video

I am currently working on an iOS app where users can watch several videos (e.g. fitness videos). The videos are all captured by my team, so I don't need access to external videos.

Now my question is, does it make more sense to store the video files offline right in the app or use some kind of online server (and which one would you recommend)? I don't want to embed Youtube videos.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: both.  If you ever want to update the videos - and you almost certainly will - you need to store them online somewhere, but you don't want your users to have to access them that way every time.  Store them online, with an in-app option to download the current version which you store on the device.

Comment: both (as above), I would say it may be enough provide a short preview of a video in the app itself (offline) and store the final videos on a server (online), that would serve both purposes and it will not increase your app's size incredibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to go online. Because the size of video may vary and huge video files would scrap user device's memory. SO it is recommended to use an external server to  host the video files.

You can also add an option to download the files if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! Do you recommend any services that fit my purpose?

Comment: I guess you can use Amazon S3 but not sure if it fits your requirement. Its just a suggestion.

Comment: I thought of Dropbox because you get 1.000GB. Does anyone know how to stream videos to iOS to be played?